# Prepositional Phrases between an Article or a Demonstrative Adjective and its Noun

Tags: preposition, adjective, article, mathematics

Is the sentence

> Sei *f* eine auf diesem Intervall Funktion.

grammatically correct? If so, what are the rules that govern such constructions and is this sentence better than the following one?:

> Sei *f* eine Funktion auf diesem Intervall.

Another example, but with a demonstrative adjective rather than an article is the sentence

> Jede in einem kompakten Intervall stetige Funktion ist beschränkt.

Comment: "beschränk**t**"

Comment: Did you really mean the first two sentences as written, or is "stetige" (as used in sentence #3) missing? As written, #1 is wrong and #2 is correct; with "stetige" it would be the other way around. It makes a difference whether the adverbial refers to a modifier or the predicate of the sentence.

Comment: @RudyVelthuis Thank you. I correct the typo.

Comment: @EndreBoth I intended them as written, but that is perhaps because I did not know including the adjective *stetige* would make a difference. Could you elaborate on this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Sei f eine Funktion auf diesem Intervall <s>Funktion</s>.

German grammar allows to split up article and noun to put *describing elements* into those "brace" elements. This braces idea is what governs German word order. However, *auf diesem Intervall* doesn't describe *eine Funktion*. It's a place where that thing resides, not a property of that thing.

This changes if you add e.g. *definierte* to the adverbial. Now it describes a property of the thing itself:

> Sei f eine *auf diesem Intervall definierte* Funktion.

This is because *definiert*, a *Partizip II* is used as an adjective and as such, has a tight affinity to the noun. The part *auf diesem Intervall* is a mere description of *definiert* in that example.

---

> Jede *in einem kompakten Intervall stetige* Funktion ist beschränkt.

See the adjective *stetig*? Same principle, the part *in einem kompakten Intervall* describes the adjective, the adjective describes the noun so the both belong into the brace spanned by *jede* and *Funktion*.

> Jede stetige Funktion in einem kompakten Intervall ist beschränkt.

So what about this one? **It means a different thing.** Be careful. Now you are telling a general "truth" about continous functions in a compact interval, not about functions that are continous in a compact interval.

Answer (score 2):

The first partial sentence sounds crooked. The original,

> Sei *f* eine Funktion auf diesem Intervall

is correct.

The other (partial) sentence is almost correct: *beschränk**t***

Comment: What makes these sentence partial? If by *partial* you mean a sentence-fragment, then don't they each have a subject and verb?

Comment: The first one is the beginning of a sentence. A sentence that starts with "Sei" usually does a little more. Like *"Be f a function on this interval ... "*. I'd expect a *"then ... "* part and perhaps a few *"and ..."* parts, here and there. And *"Every function, monotonous in a compact interval, is limited"* is generally followed by *"to ..."* or something like that. Otherwise these sentences do not make a lot of sense. Same in German.

Comment: So what makes the third sentence correct, while the first is not? I am having trouble understanding why I see some sentence with a prepositional phrase in such a location while seeing others with it after the noun.

Comment: It is a bit as if I left out the second part of the sentence *"If by partial you mean a sentence-fragment"*. Has a subject and verb too and still sounds incomplete.

Comment: The first sentence is incorrect because Funktion does not come at the end. The part that you put before should come after it. I am not one of those people who can exactly explain the grammar, but it is wrong. You don't write "Be f an on this interval function" either, do you? You write "Be f a function on this interval". Same principle. ISTM that in the third sentence, the part that comes before Funktion belongs to "stetige" and adjectives generally come before the noun they refer to.

Answer (score 0):

> what are the rules

Word order in noun phrases in German is:

**Article - adjective phrases - noun - arguments/modifications of the noun.**

(And all prepositional phrases should fall under arguments/modification.)

In your case:

```
 article |   noun   | modification
  eine   | Funktion | auf diesem Intervall
```

Word order within adjective phrases is

**modifications - adjective**

Therefore you get:

```
        modification          | adjective
 in einem kompakten Intervall | stetig
```

If you plug this in in the schema above, you get:

```
article |      modification (adj)      | adjective | noun
 Jede   | in einem kompakten Intervall |  stetige  | Funktion
```

---

> Is the sentence "Sei f eine auf diesem Intervall Funktion" grammatically correct?

**No**, because modifications (that aren't adjecives) belong after the noun they modify.